# How to stop scroll centered on a cell which is larger than screen height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm playing around with this app I found on Github and it has this code which makes the scroll stop on a cell.  The cells are full-screen size so it stops on a cell and the cell takes up the full screen.  I added a border in-between the cells and it looks kind of off because the cells are so close to being full screen but not quite.  Then I got the bright idea of adding a background behind the cells, and making the cells slightly taller than the screen, but the cell contents are still full screen.  This way the user can see the border only while scrolling, and then when it does the automatic scroll stop function, the "border" which is actually a space, is off screen.  It's the perfect solution but I'm having trouble doing it. This is the magical function that does the auto-center thing but it gets all crazy if I make cells larger than screenheight.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let cellHeight = targetContentOffset.memory.y / self.screenHeight
        let index = round(cellHeight)
        targetContentOffset.memory.y = index * self.screenHeight
    }
```

I tried adding 4 (which is the size of the "space" which is acting as a border) to screenheight in each and both places that screenHeight is used in this code and it never quite works.  If I add 4 like this:

```
targetContentOffset.memory.y = index * self.screenHeight + 4
```

It almost works.  It like puts half of the border-space thing off the screen and works consistently for each cell but always keeps a couple pixels of the border on the screen for some reason. Also screenheight is just basically UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height.

When I add 4 the way I did, it always stops 4 pixels higher than it should but it does it consistently so I need to add another 4 somewhere or something.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it working.  What I did was I only added +4 to the bottom of the cell, instead of 2 to the top and 2 to the bottom.  Then my method of adding 4 to self.screenHeight actually worked.  I think the reason this worked is because it added the spacing to the end of each cell so the cells were still showing and centering exactly the same, then when you scroll from one cell to the next you just scroll an extra 4 pixels and see the spacing but they still stop in the same place.